# How to get the first inner element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to get the first `<a>` tag in this `<div>`. This is really driving me nuts. Thanks for any help.

**HTML**

```
<div id="PGD" class="album" onmouseover="load(this)">
    <a class="dl" href="#">DOWNLOAD</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function load(dl)
{  
    var ID = $(dl).attr('id');
    var elemnt = $('ID:first').attr('id'); 
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Non-jQuery:** (*was not tagged with jQuery before, so I included this*)

- If you want to get the first child element only:

  ```
  var element = document.getElementById('PGD').children[0];
  ```
- If you want to get the first anchor element:

  ```
  var element = document.getElementById('PGD').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  ```

**With jQuery:**

```
var element = $('#PGD').find('a:first');
// or, to avoid jQuery's pseudo selecors:
// var element = $('#PGD').find('a').first();
```

and actually your function can just be

```
function load(dl)
{    
   var element = $(dl).find('a:first'); 
}
```

**Update:**

As you are using jQuery, I suggest to not attach the click handler in your HTML markup. Do it the jQuery way:

```
$(function() {
    $("#PGD").mouseover(function() {
         $(this).find('a:first').attr('display','inline');  
        alert($(this).find('a:first').attr('display'));
    });
});
```

and your HTML:

```
<div id="PGD" class="album">
     <a class="dl" href="#">DOWNLOAD</a>
</div>
```

​See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/GWgjB/

Comment: yes i've tried this. no love. What i'm trying to do with this is set the display attribute of the link from none to inline. So I was doing what you have about with .attr() attached.

Comment: function load(dl)
{    
   var element = $(dl).find('a:first').attr('display','inline'); 
}

Comment: @creocare: Please see my updated answer. The previous one should also work, but maybe you don't define `load` in the global scope. Always have a look at the console of your browser to check for errors.

Comment: If you have an anchor tag with "display:none", just use the show() function on the element in jQuery. No need to fiddle with the display style attribute, unless necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've never seen jsfiddle.net before either so that was cool.

Comment: Thanks for including both non jQuery and jQuery methods.

General rule of thumb:
If doing it by the jQuery method uses more lines than non-jQuery, don't use jQuery (since it's just extra overhead).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(ID).find(':first')
```

See `find` jQuery command.

```
$('#PGD').find('a:first')
```

Actualy I've not understanding problem, so I'm trying correct your function, to make it clear for you:

```
function load(dl)
{  

// var ID = $(dl).attr('id');
// var elemnt = $('ID:first').attr('id'); // Here is error-mast be like $(ID+':first')

 var ID = $(dl).attr('id');
 var elemnt = $(ID).find('*:first').attr('id'); 

}
```

I supose `dl` that is `$('#PGD')`. But child element `A` have not attribute `id`, what are you trying to find?

Also See: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Yeah I've tried that but it still doesn't work. I don't wont to do the the second one because it's not dynamic enough.

Comment: You may install chrome, firefox or a safari to output your objects via console. After that it will more clear for you.

PS: In the Chrome it's Ctrl+I

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#PGD").children("a:first")
```

This will give you the first child "a" tag, but not the descendents. E.g.

```
     <div id="log">
        <p><a href="foo">Foo</a></p>
        <a href="hello">Hello</a>
        <a href="how">Hello</a>
     </div>
```

Will give you : `<a href="hello">Hello</a>`